# What is the difference between hyperbola and ellipse, since they both have the equation, $\frac{y^2}{a^2}+\frac{x^2}{a^2-c^2}=1$?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Noted that the equation of ellipse is given by $\dfrac{y^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{x^2}{b^2}=1$,where $b^2=a^2-c^2$
While the equation of hyperbola is  $\dfrac{y^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{x^2}{b^2}=1$,where $b^2=c^2-a^2$

When substitute the the expression of $b^2$ into each equation

the ellipse equation

$\dfrac{y^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{x^2}{a^2-c^2}=1$

The hyperbola equation
$\dfrac{y^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{x^2}{c^2-a^2}=1$ ,which is equivalent to
$\dfrac{y^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{x^2}{a^2-c^2}=1$

So my conclusion is that hyperbola and ellipse are of the same formula, is my conclusion correct?

Comment: $\frac{x^2}{b^2}$ is always positive since $b$ and $x$ are both real numbers. Your stated manipulations makes the $b$ in one of the equations imaginary.

Comment: The main difference is that for the ellipse, $a^2 - c^2$ is positive whereas for the hyperbola it is negative. This corresponds with the fact that for the ellipse, the foci are between the vertices whereas for the hyperbola, the vertices are between the foci. This difference makes for some rather dramatic differences in how the two figures are plotted in ordinary Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Both hyperbola and ellipse are cases of conic sections (as is the parabola). In that sense they can all be described by the same [general equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#General_Cartesian_form), though this doesn't mean they have the same properties.